# Rails App Signout Redirect not working - "You do not have access to that page"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to add logout functionality to my rails app but it keeps directing me to a blank page that just says

> "You do not have permission to access that page"

This is the line in my view for my logout button:

```
=link_to("Logout", "/logout", :method => :delete, :confirm => "Are you sure?")
```

Which then brings me to my route in routes.rb:

```
match '/logout', to: 'users#logout', via: 'delete'
```

Then to my method in users_controller.rb

```
def logout
    reset_session
    flash[:notice] = "You have successfully logged out."
    redirect_to login_page_path
end
```

Even when I try commenting out the session reset, it still gives me this permission issue on the /logout page.

Does anyone have any pointers of where to look for this error? I can't seem to find anything about it online and don't know where to look...

Comment: Does it log you out, or you find yourself still logged in?

Comment: No it doesn't actually log me out. It still gives me this page even when I comment out everything in the logout method...

Comment: Do you have any before filters on the users_controller?

Comment: Good catch! Found the error there. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to omarvelous in the comments!

I had a before filter in the users_controller (this app is being created by a few people and I hadn't written in the users_controller before).

```
before_filter :require_user, :except => [:new, :create, :login]
```

Changed to

```
before_filter :require_user, :except => [:new, :create, :login, :logout]
```

Now it works!